# Delegating an ideavim shortcut to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, ideavim

I've been wondering if it's possible to map a delegation shortcut so that the next shortcut goes directly to WebStorm/PyCharm?

I know it's possible to turn ideavim on/off by a shortcut. I am also aware of ability to set a handler for keymap conflicts in settings. What I would like to do instead is to set a shortcut that will turn off / bypass ideavim just for the next shortcut.

**Example:**
Let's imagine <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> is somehow set to bypass ideavim / delegate to WebStorm/PyCharm. If I press <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd> would trigger an IntelliJ action.

Has anyone figured this out? Is that even possible?

Comment: I do not thinks it is possible. Please file and issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM with an example (steps and the use case).